# adding links to animated heading text JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to website coding. I am building a page and I am going to use animated headline js script. I want to know how can I add links to different words appearing to the animated headline in HTML or js. 
I tried to update the code but every time I click the animated text only link with "steak" appears.

```
            <b class="is-visible"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza">pizza</a></b>
            <b><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi">sushi</a></b>
            <b><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak">steak</a></b>
```

Here is the source code.
https://codepen.io/Attrexx/pen/jAjvJo

Comment: Worked when I tried replacing your html here with the same section in your codepen.

Comment: agreed but I am using clip mode of this effect. It is not working in the CLIP mode. Can you please try.

Answer (score 0):

you can use js/css library   https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ just read documentation, or search this library tutorials in youtube, with this library you can animate text and images